# Drawing app lags when too much drawing in view...How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect

When Im drawing in my app for more than 20 seconds the drawing starts to lag and it goes really slow. Is there a way I could fix this problem so it doesnt lag and runs smoothly no matter how much I draw in the view? Here is the code I have:

```
import UIKit

class DrawView: UIView {

var lines: [Line] = []
var lastPoint: CGPoint!


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {

        lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self)



    }

}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {

        let newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
        lastPoint = newPoint


        self.setNeedsDisplay()


    }


}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)

    for line in lines {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)

    }

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, true)
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, CGLineJoin.Round)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)







}
```

Comment: I would try using a single `UIBezierPath` per `touchesBegan` call and then adding to it in `touchesMoved` and closing it in `touchesEnded` then drawing the paths instead of keeping track of each individual line (which would end up being a ton after drawing for a while).

Comment: Each time you add a new point, you redraw the whole thing. This gets laggy very quickly as line length & # of points grows. One option would be to cache what's already been drawn & display it as a texture every so often, so you're only tracking/drawing a few points & then appending to a PNG representation. Save a few & only display the latest if you want to redo/undo. Bezier vector paths might be an option as well. Saw tutorials about this a while back, but don't have links handy - check out Ray Wenderlich or others for drawing app performance.